# Slate Js - Backspace not working after adding a node element

Tags: slate

I'm working on a customization for the Slate editor where a white space is automatically added to the end of a node named "rr-attribute". While the space gets added successfully, an issue arises after the insertion: pressing backspace doesn't remove the space as expected. Instead, I need to manually move the cursor using the left arrow key before the backspace works. I'm unsure of the underlying cause.

```
function adjustSpacingRealTime(value: Descendant[], editor: Editor) {
    if (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length === 0) return;

    const firstDescendant: Descendant = value[0];
    if (!Element.isElement(firstDescendant)) return;

    let previousNode: Descendant | null = null;

    firstDescendant.children.forEach((node: Descendant, index: number) => {
      const isPreviousAttribute =
        previousNode && Element.isElement(previousNode) && previousNode.type === 'rr-attribute';
      const isText = Text.isText(node);

      if (isPreviousAttribute && isText && !node.text.startsWith(' ')) {
        Transforms.insertText(editor, ' ', { at: [0, index] });
      }

      previousNode = node;
    });
  }
```

I attempted to capture the initial selection and then, after adding the white space, I used Transforms.select. However, it didn't yield the desired result.